# Extracting characters before second to last whitespace

Tags: r, string

I'm working in R and have the following:

```
"BOY MAN EL PASO ND 0023256000"
```

And I need to extract everything from the start to the second to last space.  So:

```
"BOY MAN EL PASO"
```

I've tried:

```
substr(output$CUSTOMER, 1, sapply(strsplit(output$CUSTOMER, "\\s+"), tail, 2))
```

along with tons of variations of that line.  I've found solutions to this same question in other posts but they want to extract characters between a specific character (like a slash) and when I try to adjust it I don't know how to reference a space.

Can someone help me with the R syntax on how to extract these characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `sub` with the regex pattern `"^(.*)(\\s+\\S+){2}$"`

```
> s <- "BOY MAN EL PASO ND 0023256000"

> sub("^(.*)(\\s+\\S+){2}$", "\\1", s)
[1] "BOY MAN EL PASO"
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option could be using `strsplit` to split the words and `paste` them based on the length of your vector which is the number of words like this:

```r
string = 'BOY MAN EL PASO ND 0023256000'
len = length(strsplit(string, " ")[[1]])
paste(strsplit(string, " ")[[1]][1:(len-2)], collapse = " ")
#> [1] "BOY MAN EL PASO"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Another sub:

```
text <- "BOY MAN EL PASO ND 0023256000"

sub("\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+$", "", text)
```

```
[1] "BOY MAN EL PASO"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
stringr::str_extract("BOY MAN EL PASO ND 0023256000", ".*(?= \\S+ )")
[1] "BOY MAN EL PASO"
```